# How to better join my queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this structure and some data in my database, and result I want:

[image]

For now, I use sub-queries, like this:

```
SELECT dem2.id, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 datetime 
        FROM   demand 
        WHERE  department = 'Logisitc' 
               AND action = 'Shipped' 
               AND comment = 'B' 
               AND id = dem2.id 
        ORDER  BY datetime DESC), 
       (SELECT actor 
        FROM   service_call_env 
        WHERE  id = dem2.id), 
       (SELECT TOP 1 datetime 
        FROM   demand 
        WHERE  department = 'Sale' 
               AND action = 'Email' 
               AND id = dem2.id 
        ORDER  BY datetime DESC), 
       ( Isnull((SELECT TOP 1 Isnull(Cast(demand.datetime AS VARCHAR(30)), NULL) 
         FROM 
         demand WHERE department = 'Update' AND id = dem2.id), NULL) 
         + Isnull((SELECT TOP 1 Isnull(demand.comment, NULL) FROM demand WHERE 
         department = 'Update' AND id = dem2.id), NULL) ), 
       (SELECT TOP 1 datetime 
        FROM   demand 
        WHERE  department = 'Admin' 
               AND comment IS NULL 
               AND id = dem2.id 
        ORDER  BY datetime DESC), 
       (SELECT TOP 1 dem1.datetime 
        FROM   demand 
        WHERE  department = 'Sale' 
               AND action = 'NewAddress' 
               AND id = dem2.id 
        ORDER  BY datetime DESC), 
       (SELECT TOP 1 search_name 
        FROM   demand dem1 
               INNER JOIN person 
                       ON person.person_id = dem1.USER 
        WHERE  dem1.department = 'Sale' 
               AND dem1.action = 'NewAddress' 
               AND dem1.id = dem2.id 
        ORDER  BY dem1.datetime DESC) 
FROM   demand dem1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT id 
                   FROM   demand) AS dem2 
               ON dem1.id = dem2.id
```

The `INNER JOIN` is weird but needed for my usage, because this query is an extract of a bigger one.

Could you help me, because I try some `LEFT JOIN` but my query takes a long time to execute?

Comment: You might want to format your SQL first - That's just a big wall of text at the moment.

Comment: I added some spaces

Comment: that didn't help, much. You are joining on demand like 12 times with all of these sub queries... why? I get the where clauses are different for some... but you are approaching this all wrong.

Comment: No offense but that is not a database. It is a denormalized spreadsheet that happens to be stored in a sql table. You are struggling in part here because your data is so poorly designed. You certainly don't need 12 queries to get 8 columns of data all from the same table.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a temporary table with all columns do you need and make insert or updates to feel them. This will make your code clearer.

Another point you need to check table index strategy. Check your tables about index on columns that you use on where clause and don't forget about include projection columns into the include section of indexes.